# is there a way to run js code automaticly when openning a website in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

am trying to write a code that clicks a button when a webpage is loaded, I have written the following code :

```js
 function init() {
     
    if (document.domain == "meet.google.com"){
        var Btn = document.querySelector (
            "#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.Qmt7oc > div > div.d7iDfe.NONs6c > div > div.Sla0Yd > div > div.XCoPyb > div.uArJ5e.UQuaGc.Y5sE8d.EWKsxe.xKiqt > span"
        );
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        Btn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
         
}


init();
```

how to make it run automatically when the webpage is opened

Comment: You mean locally, for debug or similar purposes, on someone else's web site? If thats the case, Google "user scripts tutorial" or "tampermonkey" to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Chrome extension to do this.

Put the JavaScript into a file called `content.js`.

Create a file called `manifest.json` that contains something like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name of your extension",
  "description": "Description of what your script does",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://meet.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You don't need the `if()` statement, since the `matches:` property in the manifest will do that check for you.

Put both files in a folder. Go to the **Extensions** window of Chrome and enable **Developer Mode**. Click on **Load Unpacked** and select the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tampermonkey to auto run your script